# shifting 0's or 1's to one side with less number of shifts

Tags: java

I have come across this test, where I need to move either 0's or 1's to one side with less number of shifts. For example, I have a list [1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1] by making 3 shifts we can move 0's to right end of the list and result is going to be [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0].

The swap can happen between the adjacent only. I have tried and was not successful.

This is what I have tried:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> arr = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1);
        List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>(arr);
        int noOfSwaps = 0;

        while(true) {
            int currentNoOfSwaps = noOfSwaps;
            for (int i=1; i<arr.size()-1; i++){
                if (arr.get(i-1)!=arr.get(i) && arr.get(i) != arr.get(i+1) && arr.get(i-1) == arr.get(i+1) ){
                    swap(copy, i);
                    currentNoOfSwaps++;
                    arr = new ArrayList<>(copy);
                    break;
                }else if (arr.get(i-1) == arr.get(i) && arr.get(i) != arr.get(i+1) && arr.get(i-1) != arr.get(i+1)) {
                    swap(copy,i);
                    currentNoOfSwaps++;
                    arr = new ArrayList<>(copy);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (currentNoOfSwaps == noOfSwaps) {
                break;
            } else {
                noOfSwaps = currentNoOfSwaps;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(noOfSwaps);
    }

    private static void swap(List<Integer> arr, int i) {
        int temp = arr.get(i+1);
        arr.remove(i+1);
        arr.add(i+1, arr.get(i));
        arr.remove(i);
        arr.add(i, temp);
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me in fix this?

Comment: sounds like some sort of leetcode problem. What do you need to return? Number of shift needed or the shifted result?

Comment: Do you need to know the number of *swaps* or the number of *shifts*? While you need 3 *shifts* to get the desired result, you would need 1 *swap* for the same.

Comment: @BabyishTank number of swaps we need to return.

Comment: @majusebetter  I need total number of swaps

Answer (score 1):

### "Swap"

In order to solve the "swap" problem, you have to implement an algorithm that works as follows:

- Let `swapCount` be `0`
- Let `endOffset` be `list size - 1`
- Iterate over the list starting at `i = 0` and check the `number`

  - If it is a `1`, continue iteration (nothing to be done here)
  - If it is a `0`, start a new iteration backward starting from `j = endOffset` and check the `swapCandidate`

    - If it is a `0`, continue iteration (nothing to be done here)
    - If it is a `1`

      - swap it with `number`
      - increment `swapCount`
      - let `endOffset` be `j - 1`

#### Implementation

```
public class SwapZeros {

    private static int swapZerosToRight(List<Integer> list) {
        final ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(list);
        
        int swapCount = 0;
        int endOffset = result.size() - 1;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            int number = result.get(i);
            if (number == 1) {
                continue;
            }
            
            for (int j = endOffset; j > i; --j) {
                int swapCandidate = result.get(j);
                if (swapCandidate == 1) {
                    result.set(i, swapCandidate);
                    result.set(j, number);
                    endOffset = j;                  
                    swapCount++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return swapCount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int swapCount = swapZerosToRight(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1));
        System.out.println("Required " + swapCount + " swap(s)");
    }
}
```

**Output**

`Required 1 swap(s)`

### "Shift"

The shift algorithm is a little simpler, since you only need to iterate into one direction; no nested loop is required.

- Let `shiftCount` be `0`
- Iterate over the list starting at `i = 0` and check the `number`

  - If it is a `1`, continue iteration (nothing to be done here)
  - If it is a `0`,

    - Swap with the number at position `i + 1`
    - Let `shiftCount` be `shiftCount + 1`

#### Implementation

```
public class ShiftZeros {
    
    private static int shiftZerosToRight(List<Integer> list) {
        final ArrayList<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>(list);
        
        int shiftCount = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < copy.size() - 1; i++) {
            int number = copy.get(i);
            if (number == 1) {
                continue;
            }

            copy.set(i, copy.get(i + 1));
            copy.set(i + 1, number);
            
            shiftCount++;           
        }
        
        return shiftCount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int shiftCount = shiftZerosToRight(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1));
        System.out.println("Required " + shiftCount + " shift(s)");
    }
}
```

**Output**

`Required 3 shift(s)`

Comment: [1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1] is an example I have used, the list can be [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]  in this case we end up with incorrect count. isn't it?

Comment: It says "Required 2 swaps", which is correct :) `0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0` -> `1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0` -> `1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0`

Comment: the swap can happen with adjacent positions only.

Comment: That's what I meant with my question above: "Do you mean *swaps* or *shifts*?" ;)

Comment: I was actually confused, then realized later you post this answer. my apologies for that.

Comment: No problem :) I extended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239127/discussion-between-majusebetter-and-krishna-thota).